# React-date-picker activeStartDate not working

Tags: reactjs, datepicker

I am using react-date-picker [library in my project](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker). I need to display placeholder in datepicker instead of already chosen date. I've managed to achieve this

[image]

but it seems that when user opens calendar it doesn't display any active day
[image].

I would like that to be by default today. I've found [in react-calendar library](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-calendar) that there is a prop **activeStartDate** which should do exactly what I need, but for some reason it does not work. What do I do wrong?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
import SVGIcon from "components/SVGIcon/SVGIcon";
import "./date-picker.scss";

const Calendar = () => {
  const [value, onChange] = useState(null);

  let today = new Date();

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
        calendarIcon={<SVGIcon name="calendar" />}
        prevLabel={<SVGIcon name="buttonArrow" />}
        nextLabel={<SVGIcon name="buttonArrow" />}
        locale="en-GB"
        dayPlaceholder="day"
        monthPlaceholder="month"
        yearPlaceholder="year"
        activeStartDate={today}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Calendar;
```

Answer (score 0):

When initialising your state
`const [value, onChange] = useState(null);` you set `value` as `null` then you pass it to `<DatePicker value={value} />`

If you want to pass today's date by default you can set `value` to today and that should do the trick:
`const [value, onChange] = useState(new Date());`

Comment: Doing this by defaults selects date in datepicker https://imgur.com/5rl9eHg. What I need is by default have a place holder and no preselected date. And when user opens datepicker to display current day in calendar like so https://imgur.com/JgdPvtl. Not sure if I explain this properly...

Comment: Maybe you should have an input with your placeholder by default and hide it when the datepicker is open. But that'd mean you need to handle the open/closed state of the datepicker via the `isOpen` in your local state